# How to find Coefficient of Variation with E(X), E(X^2) and sample size?

Tags: self-study, sample-size, expected-value, coefficient-of-variation

Given E(X), E(X^2) and sample size. How do I find Coefficient of Variation?

Variance = E(X^2) - E(X)^2

sd = square root of variance

Coefficient of Variation = sd / E(X)

however, with the values that were given, I can't get the answer I want. I wonder if the above formula is correct.

Comment: Is this related to some coursework?

Comment: hi! It's a question in one of my past year test papers. Do I need to mention it in my main post?

Comment: Hi BurningJade, welcome to CrossValidated. The `homework` tag says "A routine question from a textbook, course, or test used for a class or self-study. This community's policy is to "provide helpful hints."" -- since this is a routine question from a test being (presumably) used for self study, it counts as homework for the purposes of the tag; it affects the style of answer you get. See the brief paragraph on homework questions in the [faq](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq).

Answer (score 1):

Can you explain what you have tried, and what you can do or where the difficulty lies?

Do you know what the Coefficient of Variation is?

Do you know how $E(X^2)$ and $E(X)$ relate to variance?

Edit: all your formulas look right.

Comment: @BurningJade I just made an edit to my answer -- to say that all your formulas look correct. If you can't get the answer you think you should, something else is amiss.